# Changing SVG components in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have the following code in a tiny web page:

```
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <svg x=0 y=0>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FF0000'/>
    <circle cx=150 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#00FF00'/>
    <circle cx=50 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#0000FF'/>
    <circle cx=150 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FFFF00'/>
  </svg>
  <svg id='CtrBtn' x=0 y=0>
    <circle cx=100 cy=100 r=20 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#000000'/>
  </svg>
</svg>

<div id='status'>STATUS</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = btnHandler

function btnHandler()   {
  let divCtrBtn = document.getElementById('CtrBtn')
  divCtrBtn.onclick = function()   {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Center-Button-Hit'
  }
}
</script>
```

It works as I expect showing this for start:

[image]

And then this once I click the black button in the middle:

[image]

But this is what I want instead when clicking the button:

The red disk should change color to become cyan (*#00FFFF*) and the green should change color to become magenta (*#FF00FF*).

How should I change the code of the *function btnHandler()* to get this result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the `fill` attribute. In vanilla JS this is done with the `setAttribute` method.
EDIT:
You also need a way to target them, I've just given an `id` to each circle...

Just add those two extra lines in (see snippet below)

```js
window.onload = btnHandler

function btnHandler()   {
  let divCtrBtn = document.getElementById('CtrBtn')
  divCtrBtn.onclick = function()   {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Center-Button-Hit'
    // extra lines here
    document.getElementById('circle1').setAttribute('fill', '#00FFFF')
    document.getElementById('circle2').setAttribute('fill', '#FF00FF')
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <svg x=0 y=0>
    <circle id="circle1" cx=50 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FF0000'/>
    <circle id="circle2" cx=150 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#00FF00'/>
    <circle id="circle3" cx=50 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#0000FF'/>
    <circle id="circle4" cx=150 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FFFF00'/>
  </svg>
  <svg id='CtrBtn' x=0 y=0>
    <circle id="centreCirle"cx=100 cy=100 r=20 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#000000'/>
  </svg>
</svg>

<div id='status'>STATUS</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'll post an alternative that may also be useful to you along with explanatory comments in the JavaScript to explain how it works:

```js
/* a relatively simple function to convert a string into chunks of size 'size': */
const chunk = (str, size) => {
    /* establishing how many chunks we need: */
    const parts = Math.ceil(str.length / size),
      // converting the string into an Array, using String.prototype.split()
      // with an empty-string passed as the argument:
      temp = str.split('');

    // we return the result of this expression; first we create a new Array
    // using Array.from():
    return Array.from({
      // defining the length of the created Array:
      length: parts
      // using Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the created Array, and
      // create a new array:
    }).map(
      // here we take a substring of Array-elements from the temp Array
      // using splice, to take the elements between index 0 and a length
      // represented by the size; we use Array.prototype.splice() because
      // that modifies the Array on which it operates, allowing us to take
      // from index 0 every iteration; we then join the array-elements
      // together using Array.prototype.join():
      () => temp.splice(0, size).join('')
    );
  },
  // a simple function to handle the colour-cycling, since your colour modifications
  // are basically an inversion, FF00FF to 00FF00 (as an example):
  cycleColor = (el) => {
    // here we get the current 'fill' attribute-value of the element, and replace
    // all characters in the attribute-value that are not in the hex range of
    // 0-f with an empty space; hence '#FF00FF' becomes 'FF00FF'; this string
    // is then passed to the chunk function, and split into an Array of parts
    // each a size of 2:
    let current = chunk(el.getAttribute('fill').replace(/([^0-9a-f])/ig, ''), 2),
      // the updated colour is created by iterating over the current colour and
      // uses Array.prototype.map() to create a new Array:
      updated = current
      .map(
        // color is a reference to the current hex colour, and from the
        // original string 'FF00FF' will become an Array of values ['FF', '00', 'FF']
        // each of those hex-values will be referenced in turn. Here we
        // subtract the parsed Integer of the color (from base 16) from
        // 255 (in the rgb colour-space 255 is the maximum value), and
        // we convert that back into a hexadecimal representation using
        // Number.prototype.toString(16):
        (color) => (255 - parseInt(color, 16)).toString(16))
      // because the above use of map allows for 0 to be returned this would
      // result in an invalid hex-value:
      .map((color) => {
        // here, if the length of the color is 2 ('FF' for example),
        // we return that color; otherwise (in the case of '0') we
        // pad the String by placing a 0 at the front of the string: 
        return color.length === 2 ? color : '0' + color;
      })
      // we then join the Array-elements together with an empty-string:
      .join('');
    // and then we use Element.setAttrbute() to update the property to
    // the new colour string, using a template-literal to concatenate
    // a '#' character:
    el.setAttribute('fill', `#${updated}`);
  },

  // defining your original function as an Arrow function:
  btnHandler = () => {
    let divCtrBtn = document.getElementById('CtrBtn')
    // revising your event-binding to use EventTarget.addEventListener()
    // to bind the anonymous function to the 'click' event fired on the
    // divCtrBtn element:
    divCtrBtn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      // there was no obvious reason to add an attribute to identify the
      // elements to update, since CSS could already target them; here
      // we use document.querySelectorall() to find all <circle> elements
      // in the range of -n + 2 (the first two elements) that are found
      // inside of an <svg> without an [id] attribute; we then use
      // NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the retrieved elements:
      document.querySelectorAll('svg:not([id]) > circle:nth-child(-n + 2)').forEach(
        // and call the cycleColor function on each of them:
        (el) => cycleColor(el)
      );

      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Center-Button-Hit'
    });
  }

// as above, I changed the 'onload' event-binding to use the
// EventTarget.addEventListener() method, and call the btnHandler()
// function in response to the 'DOMContentLoaded' event:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  btnHandler();
});
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <svg x=0 y=0>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FF0000' />
    <circle cx=150 cy=50 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#00FF00' />
    <circle cx=50 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#0000FF' />
    <circle cx=150 cy=150 r=40 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#FFFF00' />
  </svg>
<svg id='CtrBtn' x=0 y=0>
    <circle cx=100 cy=100 r=20 stroke='#808080' stroke-width=3 fill='#000000' />
  </svg>
</svg>

<div id='status'>STATUS</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
- [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Great to post as blog on Dev.to or Medium. Viewcount won't reach 100 here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, @Danny, I'm not sure the answer merits an article, but thank you for the compliment.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I make use of the following "rules":

- **Make use of class names instead of IDs.** IDs must be unique in a page, so if you have more SVSs like this, it becomes easier to handle using class names.
- **Change the DOM as few places as possible.** The page will be repainted every time you change the DOM, so its better to keep down the changes. And at the same time it is also easier to keep track of what you do in JavaScript. In this example I just set a class name on the SVG and the child elements change according to the style sheet.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // click event for the entire SVG
  document.getElementById('svg01').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // if the button was clicked
    if(e.target.classList.contains('CtrBtn')){
      // toggle the class name "selected" for the SVG
      e.target.closest('svg').classList.toggle('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tl {
  fill: #FF0000;
}

.tr {
  fill: #00FF00;
}

.bl {
  fill: #0000FF;
}

.br {
  fill: #FFFF00;
}

.selected .tl {
  fill: #00FFFF;
}

.selected .tr {
  fill: #FF00FF;
}

.selected .bl {
  fill: #0000FF;
}

.selected .br {
  fill: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg01" width="200" height="200">
  <circle class="tl" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle class="tr" cx="150" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle class="bl" cx="50" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle class="br" cx="150" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle class="CtrBtn" cx="100" cy="100" r="20" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="3" fill="#000000"/>
</svg>
```